# jquery regex continuous space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to check `input` and want to show error if input is empty or entered continuous space. just one space allowed between words. e.g:

> Test ok test

```js
var pattern = /\s\s+/g;

$('a').click(function() {
  if ($('input').val().length <= 2 || pattern.test($('input').val())) {
    alert('error');
  } else {
    alert('ok go');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>check</a>
<input type="text"/>
```

It seems working, but it have issue, do this to find this issue:

Enter 5 space continuously, then click on check, it alert `error` but click again on check, it alert `ok`.

should error when user entered more than 2 space continuously.

Comment: Probably smoother to just remove the extra space on `keyup` with something like `$('input').val( $('input').val().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim() );` and dont even bother with the warning

Comment: It looks like some regex caching. Set `pattern` inside click handler would resolved it

Comment: @A.Wolff hmm Interesting problem! yeah, problem solved! thanks.

Comment: @user8001250 Indeed quite interesting. I don't know enough V8 but it seems to be a bug to me

Comment: @user8001250 Ok this is the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520853/1414562  This isn't a bug but more like a bad design

Comment: Remove `g`: `var pattern = /\s\s+/;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) method which will work better than your code in the if statement .

The trim() method removes white space from both ends of a string which in this case the value of the input , after that you can check if its equal to the empty string and will work fine

see the example below

```js
var pattern = /\s\s+/g;

$('a').click(function() {
  if ($('input').val().trim()==='') {
    alert('error');
  } else {
    alert('ok go');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>check</a>
<input type ="text" />
```

Comment: not working when `asd///more space///asdasd` or `t`

Comment: since you use jQuery than you might want to use `$.trim( someValue )` for browser support

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test:

> If the regex has the global flag set, `test()` will advance the `lastIndex` of the
>   regex. A subsequent use of `test()` will start the search at the substring of `str`
>   specified by `lastIndex` (`exec()` will also advance the `lastIndex` property).

The problem is after your regex is matched against the string, the `lastIndex` property will cause the next match to start *after* the previous match. You can verify this by outputting the value of `pattern.lastIndex` after each click.

You can fix this by manually setting `lastIndex` back to zero after each match, like

```
$('a').click(function() {
  pattern.lastIndex = 0;
  if ($('input').val().length <= 2 || pattern.test($('input').val())) {
    alert('error');
  } else {
    alert('ok go');
  }
});
```

You can also fix by getting rid of `pattern` all together and writing

```
$('a').click(function() {
  if ($('input').val().length <= 2 || /\s\s+/g.test($('input').val())) {
    alert('error');
  } else {
    alert('ok go');
  }
});
```

---

Note that you can change your pattern to `/\s{2,}/g` matching whitespace two or more times.